# Wanted to update status from "selected" value using listview(data is from database)

Tags: php

Wanted to update status from "selected" value using listview(data is from database)

Below is the code i tried

```
<input type='checkbox' name='userIDs[]' value='{$row['userID']}'>

if(isset($_POST['updatestatus'])){
$query = "UPDATE userdatabase SET userStatus='Couple' WHERE userID= '".$_POST['userIDs']."'";
 $db->query($query);
}
```

When i clicked on "updatestatus" , it will update all the selected id "userStatus" column in the database

Comment: share your html and php code

Comment: i have included in the first post

Comment: HTML : <input type='checkbox' name='userIDs[]' value='{$row['userID']}'>

PHP: if(isset($_POST['updatestatus'])){
$query = "UPDATE userdatabase SET userStatus='Couple' WHERE userID= '".$_POST['userIDs']."'";
$db->query($query);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML code, you make that array, Then you try to run a query with an array.

If you don't need to work with array try this:

```
<?php
echo "<form action='' method='POST'>";
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='userIDs' value='{$row['userID']}'>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='updatestatus' value='Update'>";
echo "</form>";

if(isset($_POST['updatestatus'])){
    $query = "UPDATE userdatabase SET userStatus='Couple' WHERE userID= '".$_POST['userIDs']."'";
    $db->query($query);
}
?>
```

If want work with array try this :

```
<?php
echo "<form action='' method='POST'>";
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='userIDs' value='{$row['userID']}'>";
// OTHER UserIDs
echo "</form>";

if(isset($_POST['updatestatus'])){
    foreach($_POST['userIDs'] as $userID)
    {
        $query = "UPDATE userdatabase SET userStatus='Couple' WHERE userID= '".$userID."'";
        $db->query($query);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: not working ,  when i click on the button , nothing happen , checked in the db nothing changed.

Comment: Edited, You have `<form>` and `$row['userID']` ? try first one.

Comment: thanks , look like added form action and it works .. thanks